# OData server library for Go-lang

Tags: rest, go, odata

I want to create an OData service in Go but I was not able to find any library for implementing the server. The [odata page](https://www.odata.org/libraries/) provides a list of libraries for Java, .Net, cpp, but does not list any for Go. I also found [GoData](https://github.com/crestonbunch/godata) but it seems abandoned and also it's stated in the very project page that it is not usable in its current state. Can you recommend me a working (preferably V4) library for exposing OData services ?